# Mysql performance on varchar with ranges

Tags: mysql

I will try to describe my problem as simple as I can.

I have a db with tables that contains columns with phone numbers ranges, e.g. `numbertype_id = 7`, `number_start = '00110000'`, `number_end = '00119999'`, `numbers = 10000` (of course I have an id pk and unique key index as well).

On the site that uses those tables, I have a search functionality, which should find a number within those ranges (if there is any). For example, user searches for '00112233', and it should return true, since there is a hit.

Now the problem is performance. I am searching only in one table per search, with a max of under 200k rows.

Being `varchar` columns (and need to be, since with `int` I would loose the leading 0's, plus the leading zeros could be none, up to 6-7), for me the obvious choice was a search like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM numberdata 
WHERE numbertype_id = 7
  AND number_start <= '00112233'
  AND number_end >= '00112233'
```

Depending on the table, that could take anywhere between 1.5 to 2.5 seconds, and it's not normal to take that long.

Does someone knows a better solution for that?

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**

I did not explained one vital detail. No matter that the number searched for returns any result or now, I still have to "offer" 45 alternatives, and have to search for those 45 numbers in part as well. So the total queries are 46 actually.

`SHOW CREATE TABLE` returns this

```
CREATE TABLE 'numberdata' (
'id' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'The primary identifier',
'numbertype_id' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
'prefix' varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
'number_start' varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
'number_end' varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
'number_count' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
'owner' varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
'owner_city' varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
UNIQUE KEY number ('numbertype_id','number_start','number_end')
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=48690 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And `EXPLAIN SELECT...` returns this

```
id select_type table      type possible_keys key    key_len ref   rows  Extra
1  SIMPLE      numberdata ref  number        number 4       const 17174 Using index condition
```

- Is it possible for the query to return 2 or more rows? Or will it always return 1 (or 0) rows?

  For any number I return only one result, or none (in case it's not present in any of the ranges). No possibilities for duplicates.
- Can we assume that all values in number_start and number_end are left-padded with 0s to the same length?

  Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Why You are worry about leading zeros? if number in range - it will be in range and without leading zeros - IF You remove them and in table and in search. You can use 2 columns -1 is varchar for store real value, second INT - for store search conditions

Comment: Probably won't matter performance-wise, but ` '00112233' between number_start and number_end is a bit shorter. Do you have an index like ( numbertype_id, number_start, number_end)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- the query can only return 1 row (or none) and never 2 or more, i.e. the `(number_start, number_end)` ranges are not overlapping for the same `numbertype_id`.
- the `number_start` and `number_end` values  are all left-padded with 0s to the same length.

Under the above assumptions, we can use a trick to use an index to fetch exactly 1 row (if there is one) that matches the criteria (not all, checking only the low end of the range) - and don't search for more rows. The check on the high end is done before the row is returned to avoid any false positive result:

```
SELECT n.* 
FROM 
    ( SELECT id, number_end
      FROM numberdata 
      WHERE numbertype_id = 7 
        AND number_start <= '00112233'
      ORDER BY number_start DESC
      LIMIT 1
    ) AS ni
  JOIN
    numberdata AS n
  ON  ni.number_end >= '00112233'
  AND ni.id = n.id ;
```

The query will only need an index on `(numbertype_id, number_start)` - or keep the one you have on `(numbertype_id, number_start, number_end)`.

Comment: interesting approach, if this will gain performance, even a little, it would help a lot. I will put to the test asap. Thank you very much.

Comment: In phpMyAdmin the query this way seems to be somewhat slower, and for some reason I am not able to implement that simple SQL into the site (using Drupal btw). I am keep trying, thought give you an update.

Comment: Try also the edited version.

Comment: thank you very much, with your variant I was able to reduce to under 150ms from 1-1.5-2 sec. Tho Drupal is also a culprit in the performance, it works. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Providing a range in two columns leads to difficult-to-optimize queries.

Have both of these:

```
INDEX(numbertype_id, number_start)
INDEX(numbertype_id, number_end)
```

Hopefully the Optimizer will pick the better of them.

If there is no need for `id`, get rid of it and promote your `UNIQUE` key to the PK.

You don't currently have any limitation that prevents overlapping ranges, is that deliberate?

Once you have promoted the index, then this is probably sufficient:

```
PRIMARY KEY(numbertype_id, number_start)
```

The other index becomes not useful, the PK likely to be better than a secondary key.

Are the numbers always 8 digits?  If so, use `CHAR(8)` instead of `VARCHAR(20)`.

Are the numbers always numeric?  Then specify the two columns as `CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin` to get a little extra speed.

Switching the PK to `PRIMARY KEY(numbertype_id, number_start)` leads to changing ypercube's approach to

```
SELECT  n.*
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  number_end
            FROM  numberdata
            WHERE  numbertype_id = 7
              AND  number_start <= '00112233'
            ORDER BY  number_start DESC
            LIMIT  1 
    ) AS ni
    JOIN  numberdata AS n USING(numbertype_id, number_start)
    WHERE  ni.number_end >= '00112233';
```

The PK is the only index needed.